# Axis, real scale

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I have a problem with the scale of my graphic. 
i need that it's a real scale(symmetric).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=left,
  y axis line style={Stealth-},x axis line style={-Stealth},
  xmin=1,xmax=710,
  ymax=2,ymin=-2000,      
  ytick={-100,-200,...,-2000},
  xtick={100,200,...,700}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the `axis equal` or `axis equal image` key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the axes lengths to be real scale, say x=7cm and y=20cm, you can use the keys `x=7cm/700`, `y=20cm/2000` for your axes. I don't think, though, it looks nice this way, using fewer ytiks seems better for me.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=middle, axis y line=left,
  y axis line style={Stealth-}, x axis line style={-Stealth},
  xmin=1,xmax=710,
  ymax=2,ymin=-2000,      
  ytick={-100,-200,...,-2000},
  xtick={100,200,...,700},
  x=7cm/700,
  y=20cm/2000,]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!